# Copy multidimensional array structure recursively for missing keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've been slamming my head against a wall for a couple days trying to write a method to recursively fill in any missing keys and empty values from 2 multidimensional arrays.

Basically, I have 2 arrays, one a "master" multidimensional array with all the expected keys and another that I want to fill in the missing values if they don't exist.

For example:

Master Array:

```
Array
(
    [title] => 
    [blog_content] => 
    [blog_files] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => Array
                        (
                            [file_id] => 
                            [site_id] => 
                            [entry_id] => 
                            [field_id] => 
                            [channel_id] => 
                            [member_id] => 
                            [member_info] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [username] => 
                                            [member_id] => 
                                            [screen_name] => 
                                            [email] => 
                                            [join_date] => 
                                            [last_visit] => 
                                            [group_id] => 
                                            [in_authorlist] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [link_field_id] => 
                            [filename] => 
                            [extension] => 
                            [mime] => 
                            [upload_service] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [url_title] => 
                            [filesize] => 
                            [md5] => 
                            [file_primary] => 
                            [file_order] => 
                            [date] => 
                            [downloads] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

Modded Array:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Title goes here
    [status] => open
    [entry_date] => 1321038883
    [entry_id] => 79
    [blog_content] => 
    [blog_files] => 
    [test_file] => 

)
```

What I'm trying to do is take the master array and add any missing keys and multidimensional structure to the modded array so it looks like the below:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Title goes here
    [status] => open
    [entry_date] => 1321038883
    [entry_id] => 79
    [blog_content] => Here's the content
[blog_files] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => Array
                    (
                        [file_id] => 
                        [site_id] => 
                        [entry_id] => 
                        [field_id] => 
                        [channel_id] => 
                        [member_id] => 
                        [member_info] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [username] => 
                                        [member_id] => 
                                        [screen_name] => 
                                        [email] => 
                                        [join_date] => 
                                        [last_visit] => 
                                        [group_id] => 
                                        [in_authorlist] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [link_field_id] => 
                        [filename] => 
                        [extension] => 
                        [mime] => 
                        [upload_service] => 
                        [title] => 
                        [url_title] => 
                        [filesize] => 
                        [md5] => 
                        [file_primary] => 
                        [file_order] => 
                        [date] => 
                        [downloads] => 
                    )

            )


)
```

I've tried some nasty head exploding recursion (my head hurts now), built in functions like array_merge (doesn't work well for numeric keys), and nothing has been able to get things working.

One thing to keep in mind though is that sometimes the modded array will sometimes have the structure of the master array, or part of the structure, with values so appending the master to the modded will overwrite any existing values.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfect fit for the often-forgotten [array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

```
$newArray = $moddedArray + $masterArray;
```

I don't know what you want to do with with multi-dimensional `$moddedArray`s though because it's not clear from your example.

Comment: Yeah, tried that. The problem with that though is that the modded array will sometimes have some of the structure of the master array so that will overwrite those values.

Comment: I think you'll need to work some more with those recursions, then.